# Validating the backuped files in s3 from marklogic database

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

How can I validate the files inside the S3 bucket after taking backup from MarkLogic database besides this XQuery:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
xdmp:database-backup-status((), xdmp:hosts())
```

which XQuery will validate it from MarkLogic, but how can I validate the size of the files for full backup files and incremental files in the S3 bucket? Whether all the files are copied with original size of the files?

In side the pod folder size are
[image]

Inside the S3 bucket:
[image: [](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZRYO.png)]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function: [`xdmp:database-backup-validate()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:database-backup-validate):

```
xdmp:database-backup-validate(xdmp:database-forests(xdmp:database("WNDSR-1")),
"s3://path/to/your/bucket/WNDSR-1", fn:false(), fn:false())
```

If you want to verify and report file sizes or anything else at the individual file level, then you can use the [`xdmp:filesystem-directory()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:filesystem-directory) and [`xdmp:filesystem-file()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:filesystem-file) methods and provide the S3 path.

Comment: Non of the scenarios work for me xdmp:database-backup-validate will validate the path for backup which we provide. but our expectation is we took the marklogic backup to the s3 bucket now after backup completes how can i cross check the all files are copied with original size as i mentioned in screen shots attached to the above question. we found one solution is restoring the backup files for new server and cross checking the documents count and size but it is costing us heavily so is there any other method which can solve the problem?

Comment: Any of the database files can/will change, especially as stands are consolidated and changes are made to content. But you could go through the folders and files in the database (using the xdmp:filesystem-* functions that I had mentioned) and ensure the folders and files exist in the backup, compare sizes, and maybe a computed hash. However, if you are looking to verify that the backup is good, a restore and verification of the restored data is probably the best and most accurate - even if it is costly.